# C++: Overwrite an element in a new-created array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

If I have an array created like this:

```
MyType *array = new MyType[10];
```

And I want to overwrite one of the elements, do I have to `delete` first the old element like this:

```
delete &array[5];
array[5] = *(new MyType());
```

Or is this completely wrong and do I have to work with something like "pointers to pointers" to fix this job? If so, how please....

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an array of *values*, not of pointers. So you'd just do

```
array[5] = MyType();
```

This requires `MyType` to support the assignment operator.

---

Incidentally, there's rarely a need for manual array allocation like this in C++. Do away with the `new` and `delete` and use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<MyType> array(10);
array[5] = MyType();
```

Note, there's no need to delete anything.

Comment: +1 for recommending std::vector. Can't do that enough it seems :)

Answer (score 3):

No.

The  individual elements of the array were not new'd, just the array itself was.

```
array[5] = MyType();   // note no  `new` here.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring an array of `MyTypes`, *not* pointers to `MyTypes`.  Because you don't `new` the elements in the array, you also don't `delete` them.  Instead, just do:

```
array[5] = MyType();
```

Note that you can also use `std::vector<MyType>` to put your `MyTypes` on the heap without worrying about the nuisances of C++ arrays.

```
std::vector<MyType> myTypes(10);
myTypes[5] = MyType();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a destructor in-place, then use placement new.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's an advanced technique, though, and given that the question is pretty basic, it's probably not what he should be doing.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, but this solution will not require an assignment operator which is good.

Comment: @Thomas: Haha! Yes indeed. The question is pretty basic... But I was mixing up `new T[...]` and a simple `new`